# Split the string with comma but not including double quotes on any number but only string

Tags: java, csv, split

I'm trying to split a String[] but while trying to do the data is not getting split correctly. my code as follows:

```
try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr))
     { int i;
    String line = null;
    System.out.println("Line value: "+line);
         br.readLine();
    for ( i=1;(line = br.readLine()) != null;i++) {
        String[] s = line.split(",");
    System.out.println("Value of row " + Float.parseFloat(datasetData.get((datasetData.size() - 1))[i])+" and column is: "+ s[1]);
    series2.add(Float.parseFloat(datasetData.get((datasetData.size() - 1))[i]), Double.parseDouble((s[1])));
```

The result produced by this is:

> "1594898820","0","","Aggregated",0.00,0.00,"N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A",0,0,0,0,0,0,0

But I need them without double quotes . Something like this:

> 1594898820,0,,Aggregated,0.00,0.00,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

Because i need to further use this data is some comparison and with quotes that is getting failed.

Comment: Why not do replace character " before split?

Comment: Why don't you use `java.nio` **and** do what @kidnan1991 commented?

Comment: Yeah, i added `            String line1 = line.replace("\"", "");
            String[] s = line1.split(",");` and It is working as expected. Thanks @kidnan1991 and @deHaar

Comment: @Sayen no problem bro, glad to help you solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

A naive way to do this is to replace:

1. The starting quote, if present, with an empty string
2. A closing quote, followed by a comma, with just a comma
3. An opening quote, preceded by a comma, with just a comma
4. The final quote, if present, with an empty string

---

## Example

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;

public class Parser {
    private static ClassLoader loader = Parser.class.getClassLoader();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            fixFile(loader.getResourceAsStream("data.csv"), "fixed.csv");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void fixFile(InputStream stream, String filename) throws IOException {
        Files.write(Paths.get(filename), fixLines(stream).getBytes());
    }

    private static String fixLines(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(fixLine(line)).append(System.lineSeparator());
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static String fixLine(String line) {
        return line.replaceFirst("^\"", "")
                .replaceAll("\",", ",")
                .replaceAll(",\"", ",")
                .replaceFirst("\"$", "");
    }
}
```

### Input

```
"1594898820","0","","Aggregated",0.00,0.00,"N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A",0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

### Output

```
1594898820,0,,Aggregated,0.00,0.00,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing another approach!!